# API-ключ для отображения карты на сайте интернет магазина

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Ребята здравствуйте.вопрос наверное глупый но вы уж извиняйте.
идёт настройка интернет магазина.
Можно ли с бесплатным API-ключом подгрузить на сайт (который пока закрыт) Яндекс.Карты что бы посмотреть функционал?
Будут ли со стороны сервиса ограничения?
или обязательно в первую очередь надо открыть сайт а потом все остальное?

Answer (score 1):

Как правило Яндекс допускает разработку сервисов с использованием бесплатного ключа. Особенно если результат также подпадает под [условия бесплатного использования](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/).

Однако если ваш сценарий использования API противоречит хотя бы одному из [правил](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/), корректней будет выбрать для себя подходящий тариф и попросить в поддержке Яндекса тестовый период на время разработки. Если за время тестирования возможности сервиса вас не удовлетворят, можете просто не оплачивать тариф.

Таким образом вы точно избежите возможной блокировки вашего магазина и каких-либо санкций со стороны Яндекса.